# Qt cross compiled for RaspberryPi 4 - application runs but is not displayed

Tags: qt, qml, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to develop a gui for a RaspberryPi 4 using Qt. I followed the directions shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmtN3Rmx9Rk) video and managed to get things up and running on the RaspberryPi. The speedometer demo that was demonstrated near the end of the video also works in my case. After getting the demo to work, I began working through the QML tutorials that were on qt.io.

I started with [QML Tutorial 1 - Basic Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial1.html), and managed to get this to run on the RaspberryPi.

I then moved on to [QML Tutorial 2 - QML Components](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial2.html). I attempted to run this application on the RaspberryPi, however, no gui/window displayed on the Pi.

Since I am new to Qt and new to cross-compiling in general, I went through basic troubleshooting steps:

1. Rebooted the Pi
2. Rebooted my Ubuntu VM that I am running Qt Creator from.
3. Deleted the build directory on my Ubuntu VM so that the application would be forced to rebuild everything.
4. Attempted to rerun the application (still no gui present).
5. Deleted the application from the Pi
6. Attempted to rerun the application (still no gui present).
7. Checked for a pid for the app on my Pi (A pid was present).
8. killed pid and reran the application, both from the Ubuntu VM as well as directly from the Pi. (Still no gui)
9. Attempted to run the demo speedometer application that I referred to in the first paragraph. This ran without a hitch.
10. I then deleted the additional code that QML Tutorial 2 introduced, and reverted back to the code that was only present in QML Tutorial 1. Reran and still did not have a gui.

What am I missing here? It doesn't appear that Qt is throwing any errors (from what I can tell).

Comment: Are you running from a terminal? Does it print any errors? Often a simple typo will cause a QML error that prevents the window from loading. But there should be something on the console in that case.

Comment: If I run the application from terminal directly on the pi itself, the application will run (hence the presence of a pid), but the gui itself does not appear. No errors are displayed in the terminal.

Comment: @kubiej21 What device do you use as a display in RPI?

Comment: 1080p monitor via hdmi0.

Comment: Are you able to build/run the same application on Ubuntu successfully?

Comment: It may take a long time to get going, but have you tried _building_ and running in pi 4?  Then you can run your app in debug mode inside of qt creator _on_ the pi 4.  Personally, I started down the cross-compiler method earlier this year and then found that compiling on the pi 4 itself was easier.  I can take a long time to compile, but then you get more visibility.

Comment: @Jarman - I tried to build/run the application on Ubuntu, but am unable to do so because qt is using g++ for the pi. It would take a bit more effort on my part to figure out how to compile for Ubuntu. I may look into doing this in the future if nothing else turns up.

Comment: *"because qt is using g++ for the pi"* -- I don't understand your comment. You can use g++ on Ubuntu too.

Comment: @RossRogers - I haven't tried yet, but am open to doing so. I have been searching for instructions on how to build directly on the pi itself, but haven't found directions that specifically state that they work for the pi 4. Lol... Di you follow these direction (https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi)?

Comment: @Jarman - when I attempt to add a DeployConfiguration for my Desktop, Qt throws the following error: "/opt/qt5pi/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" is used by qmake, but "/usr/bin/gcc" is configured in the kit. gcc/g++/embedded systems aren't my areas of expertise, so I would need to do some work to figure out how to use the correct version of gcc.

Comment: You have to use a version of qmake that's configured for your Ubuntu instead of rpi.

Comment: @JarMan - Yes, I know. Getting to that end result will take some work on my part.

Comment: You might be fine with the version of qt creator that is in the raspbian repository:  `sudo apt install qtcreator`  Otherwise, I built 5.13 with `./configure -release -qt-xcb -opengl es2 -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -qt-pcre -evdev -system-freetype -glib -openssl-linked -prefix /home/pi/qt5.13.1 && make -j4` and   5.15 with `./configure -release -xcb -opengl es2 -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -qt-pcre -evdev -system-freetype -glib -openssl-linked -prefix /home/pi/qt5.15.1 && make -j4`

Comment: @RossRogers - I've got a spare sd card laying around, so I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt install qtcreator` first.  If that version doesn't work for you, the 5.15 source is here `http://qt.mirrors.tds.net/qt/archive/qt/5.15/5.15.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.1.tar.xz` and 5.13 is at `https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.13/5.13.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.2.tar.xz`.  Compiling qt from source can take a long time.  You'll start it and leave it over night, likely.

Comment: Figured I'd report back incase anyone else stumbles upon this.
sudo apt install qtcreator qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev is what I needed to install in order to get qt working for me. I then needed to create a device as was specified in the previously linked Youtube video.